# Tracking the Updates made on a column for eg. LastLoginDate

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table 'Users' which holds the data of all the users using my application. In this table I also have details of the LastActivity and LastLoginDate. Now my customer needs the number of logins made to the application in particular month. So I need to know, is there a way I can track the number of updates made on column [LastLoginDate], one suggestion I got is by using index tracking of which I am unaware. I tried googling it but didn't result in concrete solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a trigger for the UPDATE command of your specific table and column, and inside the trigger insert records on a custom Log table where you can save login date and time for every user. Then you only need to sumarize it. If you need more details i can give you a sample. Hope the idea helps you.

Comment: Note this is the correct solution going forward, but if you want past data you are out of luck. You cannot retreive data you did not store.

Comment: What if I do not have any such existing triggers?
Even if I create a trigger now, it will fetch me records for the coming date, not the records previous to trigger creation date.

Comment: Of Course. Past information that you didn't store cannot be created. My solution is for store future logins.